# Improving stability in A-Frame and AR.js image tracking app without using third-party engines

Tags: three.js, aframe, ar.js, 8thwall-web, web-ar

I am currently working on an image tracking application using A-Frame and AR.js in a browser environment. However, I am facing stability issues in the scene, and it does not match the level of stability provided by other chargeable engines like 8th Wall. I would like to improve the stability without relying on external engines.

Is there a way to enhance the stability of the AR scene without resorting to other paid solutions? Should I manually make changes in AR.js or explore alternative approaches within A-Frame? I would greatly appreciate any guidance or suggestions to overcome this challenge and achieve a more stable AR experience.

Thank you in advance for your help!

This is code I tried:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.0.4/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://raw.githack.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/master/aframe/build/aframe-ar-nft.js"></script>
    <title>Vite App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a-scene
      vr-mode-ui="enabled: false;"
      renderer="logarithmicDepthBuffer: true;"
      embedded
      arjs="trackingMethod: best; sourceType: webcam; debugUIEnabled: true; minConfidence: 0.5;"
    >
      <a-nft
        type="nft"
        url="trex/trex-image/atlas"
        smooth="1"
        smoothCount="10"
        smoothTolerance="0.01"
        smoothThreshold="5"
      >
        <a-entity
          id="model-id"
          gltf-model="/trex/pixel-cut3.glb"
          scale="100 100 100"
          rotation="0 90 0"
          position="170 100 -240"
          smooth-position
        >
        </a-entity>
      </a-nft>
      <a-entity camera></a-entity>
    </a-scene>

    <script type="module" src="/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are doing fine. I searched a lot but nothing was found except using a marker instead of an image. It is all about the quality of the tracking image. If there is a way, it must be relevant to the image tracker system.